# Suddenly failed to call webservice from web client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic, axis

I experience a strange issue in weblogic, our web client suddenly cannot call the webservice and throw the following exception for hours continuously. At the webservice server side, no exception was caught but only http 500 was found in access log. The issue was resolved after we restart the weblogic managed server hosting the webservice.

The web client and webservice server was working fine for few months but now it suddenly goes wrong. I believe it is not the application bug because the issue was resolved after restart.

Is there anyone know the reason or having similar experience before?

```
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1781)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2957)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133)
at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:173)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
at org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllReceiver.invoke(WSDoAllReceiver.java:114)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:198)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at xx.xxxxx.common.WsUtils.onlineAddChangeOrderwCN23(WsUtils.java:403)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but... This problem is usually related by attributes deserialization/parser... probably you have ommited the lines that contains the error - something like this:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter

I get this error too when I tried to update the WSDL that my class is calling (axis client).

Verify if you have upgraded your project libraries our Weblogic version.